# WPF ListView column with Aggregated value and ProgreessBar reversed order

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have ListView with columns Price, Size and Total. Price and Size columns are bindings to items of my

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Book { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
```

in ViewModel. 
Total column should sum sizes on different prices and contains result and progress bar, which changes up to 100% on tthe last item. For example:

```
Price,Size,Total

10,2,59 (progress bar 100%)

9,6,57 (progress bar 97%)

8,5,51 (progress bar 86%)

6,34,46 (progress bar 78%)

2,12,12 (progress bar 20%)
```

Prices are ordered and unique. But a problem is totals should start from below. Lowest price, which should be the first item when aggregating, is the last item in ListView. So aggregation should use reverse order of rows to be calculated, I believe.

If ListView were aggregated from the first item in ListView, then I could use something like that:

Example:

```
Price,Size,Total

10,2,2 (progress bar 3%)

9,6,8 (progress bar 14%)

8,5,13 (progress bar 22%)

6,34,47 (progress bar 80%)

2,12,59 (progress bar 100%)
```

```
<local:SumQuantityConverter x:Key="SumQuantityConverter"/>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}" x:Key="MyItem.Template.ListView.Sum">
            <Grid>
                <ProgressBar x:Name="pBar" Opacity="0.3" Width="140"
                                             Minimum="0"
                                             Maximum="{Binding DataContext.Sum, ElementName=wind}">
                    <ProgressBar.Value>
                        <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource SumQuantityConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="wind" Path="DataContext.Book" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding Path="Price" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="wind" Path="DataContext.Sum" Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ProgressBar.Value>
                </ProgressBar>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=pBar, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Book}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Size" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MyItem.Template.ListView.Sum}}" Header="Total" Width="140"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Converter:

```
public class SumQuantityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(values?.Length > 2))
                return null;

            if (!(values[0] is IEnumerable<MyItem> book))
                return null;

            if (!(values[1] is long price))
                return null;

            double sum = (double)book.TakeWhile(ord => ord.Price >= price).Sum(ord => ord.Quantity);

            return sum;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This approach doesn't work when totals should start from the last item in ListView, because we go from the first item of ListView and cannot return back on the previous item.

Could you give an advice, how to implement my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse `ProgressBar` you may do the following

(and I was somewhat simplified the code)

```csharp
public class SumQuantityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values?.Length > 2 && values[0] is IEnumerable<MyItem> book && values[1] is long price && values[2] is long sum)
        {
            double result = (double)book.TakeWhile(ord => ord.Price > price).Sum(ord => ord.Quantity);

            return sum - result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now it's better but all Totals are shifted one row up. i.e. the most bottom row is zero, but shoud be equal to quantity of the same row. The next rows from bottom contain aggregated values which should be placed one row lower.

Comment: @VadimChesnokov I didn't shift the rows :) I just changed a progress reporting Converter which may affect only the `ProgressBar` value.

Comment: look at the screen what I mean: https://pasteboard.co/J6zfdKY.jpg

Comment: I've fixed it. It should be double result = (double)book.TakeWhile(ord => ord.Price > price).Sum(ord => ord.Quantity);
i.e. >= is replaced by > sign.

Comment: @VadimChesnokov Я рад, что всё получилось! :) Congrats! I've fixed the answer. If you think that my answer was helpful, you may accept it by checking the accept button to the left of the answer. Thank you!